# Validity of Johnson noise model in current through vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, conductors, noise

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) says Johnson noise is the electronic noise generated by the thermal agitation of the charge carriers (usually the electrons) inside an electrical conductor at equilibrium.

I started wondering if you have a junction composed of two conductors some distance such that there is current via electron tunneling (imagine an STM tip to sample junction), in calculating Johnson noise, if the resistance of the vacuum between the two conductors needs to be included.

I think it makes little sense to talk about Johnson noise coming from the resistance value of vacuum, as vacuum fails to meet a lot of the assumptions made for Johnson-Nyquist noise.

Answer (score 1):

Johnson-Nyquist noise originates from thermal vibrations of charge carriers in conductors. You are correct in that since vacuum isn't a conductor, naive application of the Johnson-Nyquist formula may not work.

However, in the case of very small tunneling gaps, as in a STM, you *do* get a modified form of Johnson-Nyquist noise; see eqn. 20 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.03803.pdf). The origin of this is slightly complicated and due to [quantum effects](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.64.3183). You can think of it as being due to thermal oscillations causing noise in the *size* of the tunneling barrier; 'increasing' and 'decreasing' it. But the form this current noise takes is different than in a 'standard' conductor.